# Match lines that start with specifc letters and exclude certain words

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, grep

I have a file that contains a series of lines as follows:

```
dbxxx
dbxxxx
dbxx
tdxx
tdxxx
sbxx
sbxxxxx
dbxx_migrated
tdxxx_old
```

Where x = one digit.

I need to create an output that would make sure to display lines that start with the following: db,td and sb and exclude any lines that has _migrated and _old.

Is this possible to do using grep?

Comment: Yes, its possible.  __info grep__ is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine regular expressions and logical operators with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^(db)|(td)|(sb)/ && !/_(old)|(migrated)/' file
dbxxx
dbxxxx
dbxx
tdxx
tdxxx
sbxx
sbxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^(db|td|sb)' file | grep -Ev '_(migrated|old)$'
```

or

```
perl -lne 'print if /^(db|td|sb)/ and not /_(migrated|old)$/' file
```